# How to calculate each element's height and use these values as a variable in function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, width

I am trying to create a simple text accordion which calculates each panel's height and return this value as a variable. I can get values with if statements like `if ( i === 0 ) { $(this).height(); }` but can't get this variable to the outside.[I can do this without using variable but it became useless in long term.](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/48/)

**Brıefly:** I want to calculate each element's `height` and use this variable inside `click` function.

**[Here is jsFiddle which includes the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/59/)**

```
var panel = $('.holder div');
var trigger = $('a');

panel.each(function(i) {
    //problem starts when i try to calculate each ele's height
    var eachEleHeight = i.height();

    trigger.click(function() {
        $(this).prev('div').animate({'height':eachEleHeight+'px'},500);

        //this works widthout var eachEleHeight but became useless
        //$(this).prev('div').animate({'height':'300px'},500);
    });

    //this is for hiding text at doc.ready
    panel.css('height','56px');
});​
```

Comment: Please be clearer as to what you're trying to achieve/what's going wrong.

Comment: This is not what's usually considered an ["accordion"](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). Please explain exactly what you expect your code to do.

Comment: @Abody97 If you fully read the question, you will see it is clear. **Briefly: I want to calculate each element's `height` and use this variable inside `click` function.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood, try this :

```
panel.each(function(i, el) {

    // create a reference to te current panel
    var $el = $(el);    

    // execute a function immediately, passing both the panel and its height
    (function(p, h) {
        // the trigger is targeted as the next link after the current panel
        p.next('a').click(function() {
           p.animate({ height : h + 'px'},500);
        });
    }($el, $el.height()));

    // set each panel height 
    $el.css('height','56px');
});
```

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/55/

Comment: **+1** Thanks for working return but i didn't understand anything from how this method works. Can you explain steps little bit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the code you posted. **`i`** is the index of the current element. Not the element itself.

Try `var eachEleHeight = $(this).height();`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgyGt/)**

Comment: This method is returnin all values for each element: http://jsfiddle.net/BgyGt/7/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to have the elements height for the accordion animation function.  This is a trick but it works. I frequently use Mootools so I'll write using it. You should be able to figure it out.

```
var orgHeight = i.offsetHeight;
i.setStyle('height','100%');
var eachEleHeight = i.offsetHeight;
i.setStyle('height',orgHeight);
```

Essentially you would be flipping the element to reveal it's height and flipping it back before the document has time to make it visible on screen.

Not sure this is exactly what you were looking for, but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of events you've used seems a bit weird.  You're actually binding a click event to all `a` tags for each `panel` element.  Try this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/pSUdQ/)

I just used the `min-height` and `max-height` css attributes to store the initial to/from height variables.  This will automatically get you your starting heights.