# how to set the size of a div depending if a table is in it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem with the height of a div.

my design is like this: i have a div with a table in it, but at the start the table is invisible. when i click a button, the table get visisble.

the problem when: the table is bigger than the div and it overlap. how to set the height of the div automaticly so that it donw overlap?
maybe somthein like this:

get the height of the table and add it to the height of the div. but how to do this?

Comment: please show your HTML & CSS code.

Comment: this question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372821/how-to-calculate-each-elements-height-and-use-these-values-as-a-variable-in-fun

Comment: The div should automatically increase its height as the table height increases. (may be i am wrong) are you giving `float` or `position` to your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this may be helpful to you...

```
<div class="boxes">
 <table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Savings</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>January</td>
<td>$100</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
```

and jquery is

```
$(".boxes").css("height", $("table").height());
$(".boxes").css("width", $("table").width());
```

Try this demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzrJ7/)

Comment: its not working, because the table is empty at the start and when i add the data and then use the css change in the height, it only add the height of a empty table